# cpan LWP failed 03modlist.data.gz

Tags: perl, module, cpan, perl-module

Recently installed `Perl 5.16` and was able to install modules fine until today.
Other than **root** when trying to install modules it gets **LWP failed with code 403**.

```
Reading '/home/user01/.cpan/sources/modules/02packages.details.txt.gz'
  Database was generated on Sun, 24 Jun 2012 18:23:03 GMT
............................................................................DONE
Fetching with LWP:
http://mwn-tlkm.archive.or.id/cpan/modules/03modlist.data.gz
LWP failed with code[403] message[Forbidden]
```

Is there a way to fix this? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a different mirror.

```
 $ cpan
 o conf init urllist
 ...
 o conf commit
 quit
```